# Increased Site Speed Sample Rate to 100 using Google Tag Manager but still getting null readings for pages that have visitors

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I changed my site speed sample rate using Google tag manager to 100% but I'm still seeing pages with visits reporting 0.00 load speed times.

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/forum/AAAAnP_FwdIncKHa4Mg_Qg/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Ftag-manager%2FncKHa4Mg_Qg

I tried the above solution

The number of pages giving 0.00 results for avg page load time hasn't really changed. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your settings?

Comment: Sure. Thanks https://imgur.com/a/wEcdjRk

Answer (score 0):

Based on this page: https://sitebulb.com/documentation/how-to-guides/how-to-increase-the-site-speed-sampling-rate-in-google-analytics/, increasing this to more than 10% is not going to make any difference. Google will always only measure the speed of a random sample of your pages. If you have pages without too many hits, I suspect you are going to be getting zeroes some of the time...